# Difference between de-structured variables and variables part of a function body

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

Is there any differences between the variables during the following strategies (de-structured versus part of body) of variable instantiation during function creation:

```
let obj = {z: {y: 99}}
let foo = ({z: {y}, x = `${y+1}`}) => console.log(x) //prints 100
let bar = (data) => {
    let y = data.z.y;
    let x = `${y+1}`;
    console.log(x);  //also prints 100
}
foo(obj);
bar(obj);
```

As far as I know both of these will create two variables, but I am wondering which is the superior approach in way of speed and memory.

Comment: Have you checked time and resources each approach requires?

Comment: So I just tested it with performance.now and the foo version seems significantly slower (bar= .06s~, foo= 2s~), so it is clear that something differs between the two; although, that I am not sure what since they look very similar to me.

Comment: Yes, similar result at stacksnippets, though closer results at `console`. The approaches apparently also take different amount of times to read how written. Not certain if "compiled" or "interpreted" is correct term.

Answer (score 1):

Could not definitively conclude approach which completes in least amount of time. stacksnippets and `console` calls also appear to influence results.

```js
let obj = {
  z: {
    y: 99
  }
};
console.profile("foo");
let foo = ({z: {y},x = `${y+1}`}) => console.log() //prints 100
foo(obj);
console.profileEnd("foo");

console.profile("bar");
let bar = (data) => {
  let y = data.z.y;
  let x = `${y+1}`;
  console.log(); //also prints 100
}

bar(obj);
console.profileEnd("bar");

let res = {
  foo:null,
  bar:null
}

res.foo = new Date().getTime();
console.time("foo");
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  foo(obj);

}
console.timeEnd("foo");
res.foo = new Date().getTime() - res.foo;

res.bar = new Date().getTime();
console.time("bar");
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  bar(obj);

}
console.timeEnd("bar");
res.bar = new Date().getTime() - res.bar;

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

```js
let obj = {
  z: {
    y: 99
  }
};
console.profile("foo");
let foo = ({z: {y},x = `${y+1}`}) => x; //prints 100
foo(obj);
console.profileEnd("foo");
console.profile("bar");
let bar = (data) => {let y = data.z.y;
  let x = `${y+1}`;
  return x; //also prints 100
}

bar(obj);
console.profileEnd("bar");

console.time("foo");
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  foo(obj);

}
console.timeEnd("foo");

console.time("bar");
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  bar(obj);

}
console.timeEnd("bar");
```